# gson.fromJson(); causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My android app receives data from a servlet as a JSON string. The string is a valid JSON string. I use the exact same ProfileBean class on the servlet side, and run gson.fromJson() to deserialize the string and store the bean in a db, which works fine. For some reason on the android side, the call gson.fromJson() causes a null pointer exception.

```
protected ProfileBean doInBackground(ProfileBean... params) {
...
InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
DataConversion dc = new DataConversion();
String jsonString = dc.convertStreamToString2(is);
is.close();
Log.d(jsString, jsonString.substring(0, 200));
Log.d(jsString, jsonString.substring(jsonString.length() - 200, jsonString.length()));
Log.d(jsString, String.valueOf(jsonString.length()) );
pfb = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ProfileBean.class);
...
}
```

This is the ProfileBean class for pub:

```
public class ProfileBean implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String email;
    String homeCity;
    String password;
    String img;
    /**
     * Takes 5 String parameters. Representing the data of a new user.
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param homeCity
     * @param password
     * @param img
     */
    public ProfileBean(String name, String email, String homeCity, String password, String img){
        this.name = name;
        this.email=email;
        this.homeCity=homeCity;
        this.password=password;
        this.img = img;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getHomeCity() {
        return homeCity;
    }

    public void setHomeCity(String homeCity) {
        this.homeCity = homeCity;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

}
```

I have been struggling with this all morning, checked the docs for Async task, Gson, and other similar stack overflow questions. I thought the problem was with the ProfileBean class, but as mentioned it works on the Servlet side. I'm stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the log message:

```
04-02 14:09:42.490 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 14:09:42.525 25449-26309/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/dalvikvm: threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411932a0)
04-02 14:09:42.560 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:223)
04-02 14:09:42.560 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at com.danielsapps.packbuddy.HostelSearch.searchForHostelsAndSetUiData(HostelSearch.java:47)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
04-02 14:09:42.565 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 14:09:42.570 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at com.danielsapps.packbuddycontroller.HostelSearchController.doInBackground(HostelSearchController.java:81)
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at com.danielsapps.packbuddycontroller.HostelSearchController.doInBackground(HostelSearchController.java:32)
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-02 14:09:42.575 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-02 14:09:42.580 25449-25449/com.danielsapps.packbuddy W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-02 14:09:42.690 25449-26309/com.danielsapps.packbuddy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.danielsapps.packbuddycontroller.HostelSearchController.doInBackground(HostelSearchController.java:81)
                                                                               at com.danielsapps.packbuddycontroller.HostelSearchController.doInBackground(HostelSearchController.java:32)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Providing the full log message would be useful. You may [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: That line (HostelSearchController.java, line 81), which line is that?

Comment: line 81 is: pfb = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ProfileBean.class);

Comment: @elloMate The only thing on that line that can trip the NPE is if the object "gson" is null. We need to see how you create that one... its creation is not in your code listing.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Thank you, that did the trick, can't believe I missed, that, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped. :)